# Dealing with database connections and ListView manipulation

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a ListView in my activity that is populated from a database Cursor using a SimpleCursorAdapter. The user can choose to edit/delete data items in the database from what he is shown in the ListView. Should I just keep a persistent database connection throughout this entire activity or would it be better to open/close a db connection whenever the user wants to edit/delete something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with open/close the database when the activity resumes/pauses, although your latter alternative is also fine.

For me is closing when the user's done with editing the whole list, and not when the user's done with a specific item. Better performance-wise? Well, that depends on the size of your database.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on why :) ? Is it better perfomance-wise?

Comment: Well, it just feels more consistent then having it to open/close when the user needs it. See my edited answer; I decided to put the rest of my comment there.

Comment: Is it okay to open the database for the first time in onResume? or should that be done in onCreate?

Comment: Open it in `onResume()`. `onResume()` will be called directly after `onCreate()`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to open it both in onCreate and onResume, and then close it in onStop? Only opening it in onResume requires that I put all my db transactions in onResume doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, never mind, then it would of course be instantiated twice. Thanks for your answer.